# Spring managed database NUnit tests fail when run in parallel with Resharper

Tags: multithreading, spring, nunit

The Goal: Run our database tests (that use different databases) to run in parallel.

We are using Resharper's Nunit option to integrate our Unit Tests into visual studio.  Resharper allows you to set the number of assemblies to run in parallel. The tests never fail when run in serial; however, when we set the number of assemblies to run in parallel to 3 or higher (maybe two, although none have failed yet), some database tests consistently fail.

Our guess, is that data providers are getting switched out from under the tests.  We use spring as an IOC and in our tests it also handles the transaction management.  Our older tests required seeded data, but our new tests expect an empty database and creates any necessary data for the test.  We think that because our bootstrap for the test fixtures is setting the connection string properties of the db provider, when another test runs in parallel, it can change the provider out from under the tests.

Either way, it would be nice to run the database tests in parallel and not lose the transaction management and test cleanup we get with spring.

The bootstrap that runs for each test is setting the connection string (and the db provider connection string).

Any ideas on how to get these tests (with different connection strings) to run in parallel.

Comment: Run the sql profiler and see if you determine the exact context the failing test is running under and see if it actually incorrect first.

Comment: Well, after adding some logging, it is definitely a problem with the connection getting changed out from under the tests.  It seems like Spring (which is handling our transactions and db providers) is using a singleton that updates when another thread runs a test against a different database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring, maybe you could edit this question and title/put the Spring config info in and see if the Spring experts know.

Comment: I edited the title to include spring.